# How to pop-up minimized program at Taskbar python

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32gui

What I want to pop-up is minimized at taskbar.

But when I run below code, not minimized program pop-up, one more program run, and it cannot be clicked or seen and simply exists in the taskbar.

```
import win32gui, win32con


hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "League of Legends")
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_SHOW)
```

What I expected : minimized program pop-up

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure that you are locating the right window using this [Finder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-finder-tool?view=vs-2015) tool. If you do not have Visual Studio, you can also download [Winspector](https://www.filecroco.com/download-winspector/)

Next, what you can try is to swap the arguments, for e.g

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("League of Legends", None)
```

Arguments for `.FindWindow` is `className` followed by `windowName` which can be found [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32gui__FindWindow_meth.html)

Moreover, you can set [specific flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) for your window to show.

For example if the initial state is minimized, you can show it by using the `SW_SHOWNORMAL` flag. Usage is as such,
`win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)`

> (SW_SHOW) Activates the window and displays it in its current size and position.
>
> (SW_SHOWNORMAL) Activates and displays a window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when displaying the window for the first time.

Comment: If program not be minimized just behind other windows, then my code work normally.

Comment: Use other flags such as `SW_SHOWNORMAL`

Comment: That's samse as SW_SHOW

Comment: I search google for 12 hours, but i can't find what i expected. And I'm korean. There's no korea documents, and I'm not familiar with english. I just 23. Sorry, I can't understand specific flags with my situation

Comment: If you would like your minimized program to pop up from its minimized state, instead of using `win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_SHOW)` use `win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)`

Comment: Now I experiment with notepad, and It works find..... But why League of Legends not pop-up, and another can't see process created like picture

Comment: Okay. Honestly its a little bit difficult to help you because of the language barrier here. But what I suspect is that your "League of Legends" is probably not the right class name. To find the CORRECT class name you will have to download an external application like Winspector to find the class name. Then you use `hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("class name here", None)`