# How do I open a minimized window using python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

is it possible to un-minimize a minimized window using python on windows 10? (I'm using python 3.8)

I would add more detail but that's really all I need to say.

Comment: Microsoft Windows?

Comment: @Heitor Chang yeah

Comment: I'm investigating, a promising lead is pywin32 and win32gui, unfortunately these do not run on Python 3.7 or 3.8. Is downgrading your Python (or using a virtualenv) a possibility? if everything fails you should look at AutoIt

Comment: A minimized window *belonging to your application* (in which case the GUI toolkit you're using will almost certainly be relevant), or belonging to another application?

Comment: @Heitor Chang yeah, i can downgrade a bit

Comment: @jasonharper it is belonging to another application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I combined information from multiple sources and got this to work (Miniconda Python 3.6, Windows 10)

```
import win32gui
import win32con

def windowEnumHandler(hwnd, top_windows):
    top_windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

def bringToFront(window_name):
    top_windows = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumHandler, top_windows)
    for i in top_windows:
        # print(i[1])
        if window_name.lower() in i[1].lower():
            # print("found", window_name)
            win32gui.ShowWindow(i[0], win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(i[0])
            break

# Test with notepad
if __name__ == "__main__":
    winname = "notepad"
    bringToFront(winname)
```

The Handler is not optimal; it spits out various processes that are not the windows in the taskbar. However, as long as your `window_name` is specific I don't think you'll run into problems. If you remove the `break`, all matches will be "opened".

Sources: [Mouse and Python Blog](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/10/20/pywin32-how-to-bring-a-window-to-front/)

[Another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471178/how-to-pop-up-minimized-program-at-taskbar-python)